# binary '>=': 'std::chrono::system_clock::time_point'

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, c++-chrono

I am not sure how to get ride of this compiler error:

```
error C2676: binary '>=': 'std::chrono::system_clock::time_point'
```

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
  std::chrono::system_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  std::time_t now_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now - std::chrono::hours(24));

  if (std::chrono::system_clock::now() >= now_c)
  {

  }
}
```

Here is what the compiler outputs:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>d:\dev\cpptests\test\test\source.cpp(25): error C2784: 'bool std::operator >=(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'std::chrono::system_clock::time_point'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\utility(311): note: see declaration of 'std::operator >='
1>d:\dev\cpptests\test\test\source.cpp(25): error C2784: 'bool std::chrono::operator >=(const std::chrono::duration<_Rep,_Period> &,const std::chrono::duration<_Rep2,_Period2> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::chrono::duration<_Rep,_Period> &' from 'std::chrono::system_clock::time_point'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\chrono(538): note: see declaration of 'std::chrono::operator >='
1>d:\dev\cpptests\test\test\source.cpp(25): error C2784: 'bool std::chrono::operator >=(const std::chrono::time_point<_Clock,_Duration> &,const std::chrono::time_point<_Clock,_Duration2> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::chrono::time_point<_Clock,_Duration2> &' from 'time_t'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\chrono(905): note: see declaration of 'std::chrono::operator >='
1>d:\dev\cpptests\test\test\source.cpp(25): error C2676: binary '>=': 'std::chrono::system_clock::time_point' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Well, you cannot directly compare `time_t` (which is from old C land) and `chrono::system_clock::time_point`. Why don't you make `now_c` of type `time_point`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you to use type deduction with auto for this kind of case, as it makes the code much clearer. Also, as said in the comments above, the **std::chrono** facilities are not directly compatible with **c-style time_t**. I would recommend to keep using just **std::chrono** since it is  more type-safe than it's counterpart.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  auto now_c = now - std::chrono::hours(24);

  if (std::chrono::system_clock::now() >= now_c)
  {
    std::cout << "it works!" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are try to **compare** a C++ time_point with a C time! And there is no operator `>=` to compare. Then you try to compare `nanosecond` with `second`
The **time_point** has a function named `time_since_epoch` and you can use it.
Using `auto` can help solve the problem but not understanding what happens and what is under the hood!
So you simply can compare(**not good**):
`if ( now.time_since_epoch().count() >= now_c)`

And the **better** code is:
`std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::seconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count()`

Because `time_t` is per `second`

---

```
  if ( now.time_since_epoch().count() >= now_c){
     std::cout << now.time_since_epoch().count() << '\n';
     std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::seconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count() << '\n';
     std::cout << now_c << '\n';
  }
```

the output:

```
1487879248873636085
1487879248
1487792848
```